# Display specific word in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to display "SWEUserName=r.m12345"

Process  RequestDetail    4       f45d912121f4:0      2017-01-01 10:04:13     SWE Command Processor - Handle user request: SWEFo=SWEEntryForm SWESD=3 SWENeedContext=false SWENoHttpRedir=false SWECmd=ExecuteLogin W=t SWEUserName=r.m12345 SWESPNR= SQOIWO= SWSAH= SWEH= _tid=12345678 SWEC=0 SWEW= SWEBID=-4 SRN= SWETS=1234567890 SWEWN=

Code: $Display | Select-String -Pattern 'SWEUserName*' -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch

Expected Output: SWEUserName=r.m12345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a regular expression for this.

Example below:

```
$sample = 'Process RequestDetail 4 f45d912121f4:0 2017-01-01 10:04:13 SWE Command Processor - Handle user request: SWEFo=SWEEntryForm SWESD=3 SWENeedContext=false SWENoHttpRedir=false SWECmd=ExecuteLogin W=t SWEUserName=r.m12345 SWESPNR= SQOIWO= SWSAH= SWEH= _tid=12345678 SWEC=0 SWEW= SWEBID=-4 SRN= SWETS=1234567890 SWEWN='

$isMatch = $sample -match 'SWEUserName=[^\s]+'

if ($isMatch) {
  Write-Output $Matches[0]
}
```

From: https://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html

> As a side effect, the -match operator sets a special variable called $matches. This is an associative array that holds the overall regex match and all capturing group matches. $matches[0] gives you the overall regex match, $matches[1] the first capturing group, and $matches['name'] the text matched by the named group "name".